# ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork() not working as expected

Tags: android, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager

I'm trying to temporarily force the device to use mobile data. I'm using `ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()`,

```
    NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    request.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request.build(), newRequestTransportCallback(connectivityManager),
            (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
```

Where `newRequestTransportCallback()` returns,

```
new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Network available: " + network + ", binding...");
                if (cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network)) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Bind successful to network: " + network);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG,"Bind failed to network: " + network);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnavailable() {
                Log.w(TAG,"Network not available");
            }
        };
```

I can see from my log statements that the request and bind succeed. However, when I subsequently call `ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)` it tells me the network is disconnected (and I've tried polling to see if there's some delay in updating the network info with no success either).

Comment: Think that you can't just force device to use particular type of network. addTransportType method is dedicated for checking the connection on selected layers of networks.